# Why do I get multi-year-old questions in my feed?

Tags: bug, feed

Today, I got this 3-year-old question in my rss feed: Is it glitching?

[What percentage of its capacity should I aim to run a network at?](https://serverfault.com/questions/239072/what-percentage-of-its-capacity-should-i-aim-to-run-a-network-at)

Comment: Hmmh, the question has long been answered and accepted so the Community bot shouldn't bother with it but the second answer is from you and marked as Community Wiki. Maybe that's the reason for this.  I am migrating this to [meta.se] as this isn't really [SF] specific.

Comment: There's nothing in its [timeline](http://serverfault.com/posts/239072/timeline) for today either, and I went through the first few pages of the active questions list (in case it was a deletion event, which I don't have the priv to see, or some community bump related thing) and also didn't see it there. Weird.

Comment: What exactly is your RSS feed? Can you post its source?

Comment: Sure: it's "http://serverfault.com/feeds/tag/capacity-planning"

Answer (score 5):

Sigh; yes, that's probably me; I've disabled the smoke-test server related to this while I investigate. Almost certainly the same bug as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345357/feed-email-notification-misfiring/345506#345506), manifesting in a slightly different way. Both look very-much like the wrong offsets being applied to a pre-indexed chunk'o'data. For you it meant you got slightly the wrong page of records; for other folks it has meant the wrong tag entirely - but the per-tag pre-indexes are stacked adjacently, so that's *actually* the same thing... ish.

Comment: So should this be closed as duplicate?

Comment: A few days ago I saw old questions simply by clicking on "Questions" at the top of this Webpage (Mobile view). I answered a few of those questions, some answered and some not; scored a few Points for one as the answer was accepted (as the only one). So not RSS Feed limited nor does it seem a dupe of the other. - Past couple of days I've not seen any old questions (on the first page) so for me it was fixed, now.

Comment: Much appreciated: you can nclose this with my thanks, then.